# Gaming Questions of the Week #8

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, blog, question-of-the-week

In an effort to try and keep the Question of the Week going, please submit your suggestions for this week!

### Previous Questions of the Week:

- First week's question - [Minecraft's World Size](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/minecrafts-world-size)
- Second week's question - [Pokemon Missingno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19638/10)
- Third week's question - [Tips for not getting lost underground](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/qotw/get-lost)
- Fourth week's question - [Does GLaDOS hate Atlas, the Blue Robot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20540/3015)
- Fifth week's questions - [10 Awesome things to try in Minecraft](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/2011/05/09/10-awesome-things-to-try-in-minecraft/)
- Fifth week's questions - [Why should I pay for that game?](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/2011/05/17/why-should-i-pay-for-that-game/)

Please post any of **this week's questions** that you feel is of worth and the reason why. If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

Comment: Question: Typically when it's time to recommend a question, I review the [Hottest Questions This Week](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/?tab=week) for anything that transcends one game or is just a breakout hit. Usually, if I find something in that category, someone else has already recommended it. How adverse are we to questions that are specific to just one game? Are these fine as long as its a popular game/question?

Comment: @Shaun Of the 6 questions selected, 5 of them are specific to a single game. I'd say being a popular question is fine enough - if it's not a popular game, then an exemplary question and accompanying post can probably spread the word better about an unknown game.

Comment: So, whatever happened to QOTW anyway?

Answer (score 3):

[What's the secret to playing pyro?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23755/whats-the-secret-to-playing-pyro) is a good one

Answer (score 1):

[Can I safely uninstall games purchased from Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23296/can-i-safely-uninstall-games-purchased-from-steam)

While not exactly a detailed or difficult question to answer, it does serve to help reinforce the nature of cloud-based gaming platforms.

Answer (score 0):

[Best worded question title in a while](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22862/so-i-was-out-drinking-last-night-how-do-i-remove-a-tattoo)

Also a good discussion to have about it being a 'mature' game and the whole Australia censorship hoopla.

Comment: I'm annoyed the answers didn't follow suit and have stories as well...

Comment: I'm glad to see that you put mature in quotes.  I haven't played the sequel, but my impression of the first game is that it is more sophomoric than mature.